Bonding additive for mortar in brick parge?
I have a 4’ high section of exposed brick foundation wall which needs parging before I insulate it.
I’m making my own softer mortar mix, but was curious about using a bonding additive.  Mostly, is it reasonable? And if so, what sort of ratio do I want to use? I know of old timers who used Elmer’s glue by the bucket and had good results, so I assume it’s a pretty high ratio?
